# Interpolate each row of 2d array with same 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

**Question: How do you you linearly interpolate each row of a 2d array with the same 1d array?**

I have 2 sets of x-coordinates and a matrix of y-coordinates, I want to do this without the loop:

```
for k in range(len(y[:,0]))
    y_want = np.interp(x_want,x_have,y_have[k,:])
    y_new.append(y_want)
```

Is there a built in numpy function that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scipy.interpolate.interp1d:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,11)

y=np.vstack((np.sin(x),np.cos(x),np.log1p(x)))

xi=np.linspace(0,1,101)

intf= interp1d(x,y,axis=1)

yi=intf(xi)

plt.ioff()
plt.plot(x,y.T,'x',
         xi,yi.T)
plt.show()
```

Comment: For some reason this took longer than my loop. But, it is possible I am doing something wrong.